# Excel function (COUNTIF)

Tags: excel

I need help,after when i used COUNTIF in excel. I would know how many columns there are not matching right! So my question is how do I know which columns are not matching in my table?
thank you

Comment: Have a look here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759

Comment: You may try `MATCH()` function.

Comment: Using `MATCH()` function is highly suggested here as given by @Harun24hr Sir, since `COUNTIF()` will start giving false positives after certain amount of rows, try using as mentioned above ^^^